# Merging helm templates without overwriting with empty values

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm working with helper chart in helm to be able to overwrite common template from lib chart.
To merge templates I'm using the following util:

```
{{- define "mylibchart.util.merge" -}}
{{- $top := first . -}}
{{- $overrides := fromYaml (include (index . 1) $top) | default (dict ) -}}
{{- $tpl := fromYaml (include (index . 2) $top) | default (dict ) -}}
{{- toYaml (merge $overrides $tpl) -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Problem I faced with is the following.

Common template:

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.global.container.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.application.name }}
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.application.name }}
```

Overwriting template:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: Custom value
        annotation: custom
```

Result:

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
spec:
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: Custom value
        annotation: custom
```

**Result I want to achieve**:

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.global.container.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.application.name }}
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: Custom value
        annotation: custom
```

I've already checked sprig lib but didn't find other function to be handy in this case.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing, so please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65823646/edit) and include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating how you're invoking that `{{- define "mylibchart.util.merge" -}}` template, along with your version of helm, since that could make a big difference, too